# Odd signal not showing correctly in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, matlab-figure

```matlab
t=-10:0.001:10
x=sinc(t);
subplot(321)
plot(t,x)
title 'orignal sinc wave'
%x(-t)
a=sinc(-t);
subplot(322)
plot(t,a)
title 'negative'
b=(x+a)*1/2;
subplot(323)
plot(t,b)
title 'even part of the signal'
c=(x-a)*1/2;
subplot(324)
plot(t,c)

title 'odd part of the signal'
d=c+b;
subplot(325)
plot(t,d)
```

[image: result]

Comment: Please [edit] your post to describe the problem, what you are trying to plot and why your result is not what you expect. See [ask].

Answer (score 1):

`sinc(t)` is a symmetric function, so `x=sinc(t)=sinc(-t)=a`, thus, your panel 4, `c=(x-a)*1/2` yields exactly 0 for all t values.